# PHP URL Shortening/Re-Writing

Tags: php, htaccess, redirects

I'm looking to shorten some links, by re-directing. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is: I have files at www.mysite.com/qr/quicklinks/User/ but I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow make it so it's just www.mysite.com/user? This would be brilliant if it can be done and possibly in PHP too? I've tried a few things but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a .htaccess file and mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^qr/quicklinks/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Depending on the server, that's case-sensitive. Adjust the URL if necessary.

If that fails, try this PHP code:

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.site.com/Users/" ); 
?>
```

It won't support wildcard files though.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I've created a .htaccess file and places it on the server, then put your code into it. Does anything else have to be in the .htaccess file?

Comment: It requires that `mod_rewrite` is enabled, I updated my answer with some PHP code.

Comment: Struggling with this, I've never really set up a .htaccess file before. It's not really doing anything, just not letting me access anything on my server now. I delete the .htaccess file and it's back to normal... Is there anything that a .htaccess file MUST have in order to run?

Comment: Hold on, which directory did you put the .htaccess? It could also be my syntax, that was done from memory. I'll verify it on my server quickly.

Comment: I put it in the root. I'm looking for it to do the following if possible dude: www.mysite.com/QR/QuickLinks/'XXXXXX' - So, whatever is 'XXXXX' can be found by going to www.mysite.com/'XXXXXX'

Comment: Try the new .htaccess I posted.

Comment: Still no luck mate, I have the .htaccess file located in '/public_html' if that's any help? I'm just getting a URL not found every time at the moment...

Comment: Try putting in the directory you want to redirect FROM.

Comment: Still no luck, does it take a while to come into effect or anything like that?

Comment: Nope, .htaccess files are instant, since they're read each time the directory is accessed. I'd move this to chat, but your reputation isn't high enough yet. I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Don't be sorry. you have been very helpful. I'll keep on searching.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can just use Bit.ly for free and they have an api where your site can generate URLs.

Comment: Bitly is cool because they handle everything for you.  If you want something that you can host yourself, then http://yourls.org/ is a nice free start.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble actually implementing the Bit.Ly at the moment. The way my site works is, the user inputs a contract number and then that creates a directory, calls for a QR Code (Via Google) using the link.. How would I get that Bit.Ly into the Google script at the same time?

Comment: Where is the google script you are using?  Ill take a look